# WPF: Placeholder

Tags: wpf, text, textbox

It's the following situation:

I've a WPF project with three textboxes. In these textboxes is the content something like this:

Textbox 1:

net.tcp://server1:61594/printerengine/printerserver

Textbox 2:

net.tcp://server1:61594/printerengine/printeradmin

Textbox 3:

net.tcp://server1:61594/printerengine/printeradmin

Because of the reason the paths stay the same all the time and only the server name changes, there should be an extra textbox for the server name only.

In the textbox 4 should be the server name filled in only:

Textbox 4:

server1

If you want to change the server name, it should be possible to change it in the textbox 4 and it should automatically rename the server name in the path in textbox 1-3.

I'm hoping you can understand me and give me a little bit help.

Greetings,
Lars

thank you for your answer. Not really sure if it would help me but I found this tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

This is written in C# but I rewrote it to WPF:

This is my code:

```
Public Class DateConverter
   Implements IValueConverter

   Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object) As Object
      Dim [date] As DateTime = DirectCast(value, DateTime)
      Return [date].ToShortDateString()
   End Function
   Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object) As Object
      Dim strValue As String = value.ToString()
      Dim resultDateTime As DateTime
      If DateTime.TryParse(strValue, resultDateTime) Then
         Return resultDateTime
      End If
      Return value
   End Function

   Public Function Convert1(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert

   End Function

   Public Function ConvertBack1(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack

   End Function
End Class
```

And this is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Grid>
      <src:DateConverter x:Key="dateConverter"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,8,0"
           Name="startDateTitle"
           Style="{StaticResource smallTitleStyle}">Start Date:</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Name="StartDateDTKey" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
    Text="{Binding Path=StartDate, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}" 
    Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>

   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Not really working. Anyone who can help me? Thank you.

Greetings,
Lars

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, that's WPF code only. You have not even created a `Converter` for your scenario, you can create a `converter` which accepts server name and a `CommandParameter` (`printerserver`/`printeradmin`) and return the required url combining them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx), something like this -

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=Textbox4Name, 
                   StringFormat='net.tcp://\{0\}/printerengine/printerserver' />
```

refer - http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/